# ionic app distribution so big

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I just created an Ionic app. Now I'm thinking about publishing.

Just a few days coding, but the output distribution is 50MB. Even it's iOS app without the crosswalk.

That's crazy, is that normal? What should I do? Check or config?

Update, the size of www folder:

```
$ du -h -d 1 www
4.0K    www/css
8.0K    www/img
 48K    www/js
 14M    www/lib
 28K    www/templates
 14M    www
```

**Update: I used https://github.com/diegonetto/generator-ionic, works fine.**

Comment: Have you somehow managed to distribute you app with the /node_modules or /bower folders?  What cordova-plugins (if any) are you using?

Comment: I think that's the point. Has any advice like gulp task for ionic? Thanks!

Comment: How does you www-folder look? How big is it?

Comment: I think all assets include useless files for production are in the www/lib those are bower plugins. But I can't imagine ionic don't do anything with those files. And I didn't see a document mantion need to deal with thoes when release.

Comment: I can find some yeoman generates for ionic but I don't know which one can fix my problem well for now. Let me see.

Comment: Any update on this issue I am unable to descrese my .ipa file size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default template when starting an Ionic app only contains "www\lib\ionic" when it comes to bower plugins. If you do not use any of the other libraries inside www\lib then it should be safe to delete them.

Update: 
The Out-of-the-box gulp task does not clean up your bower folders for you By renaming your .apk's or .ipa-files to .zip it is possible to further analyze whats causing massive file sizes.

Comment: I think that's it. I'm trying to use yeo-man ionic generator with grunt tasks to deal with those Bower plugins.

Comment: Sorry, I just spent an entire night to add the task to compress assets. I found the problem is not from www/lib.

Comment: If you rename your .ipa (or .apk) to .zip and check its contents you should be able to figure out what's causing the massive file size.

Comment: I found grunt task didn't delete useless files in bower components. And I generated some splash by `ionic resources`, images are crazy big like 10mb just one file.